# Want to generate random number including quotes

Tags: php

I want to genetate a random number like a,b,c,'and ".So far i have tried

```
<?php 
function generateRandomString($length = 9) {
$char = 'abcd';
 $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <$length; $i++) {
        $randomString = $char[rand(0, strlen($char) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$ran=generateRandomString();
?>
```

It generates a,b,c,d as random string
But if i try " like `$char='abcd&quot;';` then it generates q,u,o,a,& etc.

Comment: Why are you using an HTML entity in there?

Comment: You probably want to escape special characters after the shuffle.

Comment: wouldn't the backslash be printed too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    function generateRandomString($length = 9) {
        $char = 'abcd"\'';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i <$length; $i++) {
            $randomString = $char[rand(0, strlen($char) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
    $ran=generateRandomString();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
$char = 'abcd"\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape and pass the `quote`.

```
$char = 'abcd\''
```

Comment: Explain downvote ? Someone is just downvoting my answers...don't know why...Moment ago this was the accepted answer...